# Python file truncate with one writer and one reader?

Tags: python, file, posix

Let's say I have two processes, a writer and a reader. The writer is a python process that has its stdout redirected into a file. The reader is a python process, whose goal is to read from the file, and do something with the bytes. Once it has used the bytes, it wants to shorten the file to keep it from getting too large. In other words, the file is being used as a buffer between the stdout from one file and the reader. Is it safe for the reader to use python's [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) method once it's done processing the bytes? Will this cause any problems for the writer?

Let's assume I'm only interested in Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: Is there a reason not to hook them up in some other way that is intended to work as a FIFO, e.g. a named pipe? Or even simpler if one is a parent and one a child, a simple pipe? Files are not well suited to this, because you can't truncate off the *beginning* of the file, only the end, so it becomes complicated to coordinate such that the reader only reads complete messages from the writer, the truncation of the file doesn't discard unread data, and the writer and reader can properly reset to the beginning of the file after truncation.

Comment: I was thinking as I was writing this that a pipe might work! Though let's assume for other reasons I prefer to use a file. So the contents of the "buffer" remains persisted if there's some weird crash. I may switch to a pipe anyway, but In would still like to know the answer to this.

Comment: And no, it's not safe, between the time you finish reading and the time you call truncate the writer may have written more data that you will delete without ever reading. You need some synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @augray: If you must use files, I'd suggest a rotating file system rather than trying to modify one file in place. Switch between files, have the writer write a message indicating it's done with the file and the name of the next file it will use at the end of each file once it's reached a certain size, number of messages, what have you. Have the reader responsible for deleting files once they're consumed once it's moved to the next one.